# Debug Node.js on Netbeans

Tags: node.js, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I have NetBeans 8.0.2 and the latest Node.js plugin.  Is it possible to debug my server code inside Netbeans?  I can set a breakpoint, but it never gets called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only in Dev builds available from [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/), not in 8.0.2. It will be in upcoming NetBeans 8.1